# how does chronicle queue enable remote appender and tailer

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-queue

I just start to read the latest V4 documentation. It suggests for remote append and tail, it is recommended to use `chronicle-engine`. Does it require the enterprise support for that set of functionality ? I looked around the test packages of `chronicle-engine`, and found out this test class `WireRemoteStatelessQueueClientTest.java` seems to be relevant but is entirely commented out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I should just switch to V3 implementation.